# How can I find credit consumption of my planet API key?

Tags: planet

I'm using Planet API and I'll be making numerous requests every day. So the answers to this question will be a great help.

1. How to find credit consumption of API calls made on planet API?
2. Is there any section in Planet.com?
3. Will I be charged again if made the same API request again?

same API request meaning - Same input (item_id,item_type) to the same API(search imagery API, or download imagery API). Exact same request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to https://www.planet.com/account/, click Organizations, and click Usage, you should see your usage data.

Answer (score 2):

The total credit consumption can be seen in the following way:

If you login into planet explorer - > clicks on the blue astronaut at the top right-hand corner -> go to account settings at the bottom -> click on organizations on the left side - > click on usage on the header.

You should be able to see your consumption.

Other points to note.

1. If the same image is downloaded twice, you'll be charged twice.
2. Activation of the asset doesn't consume any credits.
3. Similarly, searching of imagery doesn't consume any credits.

Planet Labs only charges for downloading imagery.